# Do not allow null in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose. I want to create a field with `not null` as sql does means when a null value try to insert in a collection, it shouldn't allow to store null value.

Comment: Possibly the [required](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-required) attribute? Or you can use a [custom validator](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html). So you could have searched for this in the documentation.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Mogoose validators](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) to validate your model before saving it. There is no way for doing it at `mongodb` level. `MongoDB` is a NoSQL, schemaless database.

The required option might be useful

```
SchemaName = mongoose.Schema(
fieldName: {type: type, required: true}
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schemaname = new mongoose.Schema({
field1: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
field2: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Schemanames",Schemaname);
```

Comment: Do add ` ` between the code. It makes them more readible.